# Spring Integration SFTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

I’ve been running into this issue for a while now and need some assistance solving it. This error randomly presented itself:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing ‘example/of/directory’ to local directory;
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingExecption: Failed to execute on session;
nested exception is org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item
```

This occurred after upgrading Log4J, not sure if I also need to upgrade Spring Integration as well. A little stuck here.

Comment: You need to show your code and configuration, and **complete** stack trace (edit the question). The error means you are using the caching session factory and have run out of sessions, implying that sessions are not being closed properly (or the pool is too small for your workload). Truncated stack traces are less than uselesss.

Comment: Let's see if your error in the end shows exactly this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8782 !

Comment: @GaryRussell how can produce more useful logs? I think I saw a suggestion on here that recommended I set my logger to trace. How can I do that?

Comment: @ArtemBilan has anyone in that thread been able to resolve the matter? If so, what was the root cause? I wasn’t able to see a solution in the comments.

Comment: There is a mentioning of this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8693. And the problem indicates that `SshdSocketAddress.toSshdSocketAddress` resolves to host name, where your `known_host` entries are IP-based. So, my suggestion was there to try to add an entry based on a host name of that IP.

Comment: @ArtemBilan how can I produce a more useful log? How do I set it to trace? I’m using Log4J2.xml configurations, not too familiar.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I’m not using SFTP Integration v6. I’m on v5.

Comment: OK. So, give us more info to determine what is going on.

Comment: @ArtemBilan It looks like authentication was the issue. Jsch, with cancel. I changed the preferred authentication to password, it ran but the Auth was cancelled.